# How to use "SUMPRODUCT" to get the boolean result from two columns different type?

Tags: excel, office365

I am trying to use "SUMPRODUCT" to get result which equals to two criterions:
a. Get date from a column range and put into WEEKNUM(), and compare to the WEEKNUM() of today. If they are equal, then return '1'
b. Get name from  a certain cell, compare with a column of Name. If they are equal, then return '1'

**c. SUMPRODUCT a and b, I can get a result represents "How many
appointments has been arranged by a certain person in this week"**

I use this formula which works perfect on Google Sheet, but when I try to use it on Office Excel, it shows "#VALUE!".

The complete formula shows as below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Q12:Q980=H2)*(WEEKNUM(F12:F980)=WEEKNUM(TODAY())*((F12:F980)>=TODAY())))
```

A screenshot from the sheet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2od4.png)

Cloud anyone help to solve this problem, or better solution?

Thanks~

Comment: Are the 'blank' cells in column F actually blank, or formulas returning ""? The latter would cause a `#VALUE!` error with `WEEKNUM`.

Comment: I assume what you mean is, if the column F is all filled, might solve the "#VALUE!"?
I tried using only WEEKNUM(F12:F13), the issue still exists. I will also try your suggestion.

Comment: I can't tell from a picture, but perhaps the data in column F is stored as text, rather than actual dates.

Comment: Hi Rory,
I did try to store the F column as "Genernal" and "Number", they don't work....
Thanks for your input~

Comment: Hi Rory,
I also try 
WEEKNUM(F12:F13) -> doesn't work
WEEKNUM(F12:F$13) -> doesn't work
WEEKNUM(F12:F12) -> work
WEEKNUM(F12:F) -> doesn't work

Pls share with if you've got any ideas...
Thanks~

Comment: Did  you array enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than just Enter?

Comment: Hi Rory,
Sorry for the late reply.

I found out that WEEKNUM can't handle the column calculation in Office Excel, so I give up using WEEKNUM.

Instead, I added a column which include a formula "=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A$6,H12,1)", which means the "First Visit Date" minus the start date of this week, and if the result <= 5, which means the "First Visit Date" is within this week(work day). Not the best solution, but solve my problem now...

Comment: By the way, I also found out something interesting, A lot of formulas or settings can't be added when using "Web Excel", but if applying those formulas or settings on traditional excel, then import into Web version excel, most of those functions are workable. For example, "Define name"

Anyway, really thankful for help me a lot~